# Want to serve hyperlink within a string which is in an array and passed as a prop, in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am serving static text data from an array which gets 'Mapped' further in my React component

```
const LinkElement = () => <Link to='/some-redirection-in-the-same-app'>Click here...</Link>

const EyelashGrowthData = [
    {
        key:"How does bimatoprost 0.03% ophthalmic solution work?",
        data:`It is believed the growth cycle (anagen) phase is increased of your eyelash hair cycle. Anagen is the
        growth phase of all hair. The increase in the length of the anagen phase therefore increases the
        number of hairs in this growth phase.`   
    },
    {
        key:"Is a doctor’s consultation and prescription required for this treatment?",
        data:`Yes, this is a prescription-only medication to grow the eyelashes longer, fuller and darker, indicated
        for people with inadequate or not enough lashes. This treatment needs to be prescribed by a doctor
        to assure the proper treatment and use. Complete the ${LinkElement} now.`   
    }
];
```

this `EyelashGrowthData` is further passed to some component in a prop
and becomes `data` prop of the below component and served like this
There may be very much variants of `data` which may not have hyperlinks
but some of them have hyperlink which should be there.

There are many levels of components before the `EyelashGrowthData` gets passed to this below component

```
export ({data}) => {
   data.map(item => { 
       return (
            <>
            <Typo>
                {item.key}
            </Typo>
            <Typo>
                {item.data}
       //this should render a ${LinkElement} in {item.data}, which will work perfectly as a link
            </Typo>
            ......many other thing
            </>
       )
   })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach could be to change your data keys to React functions that return JSX:

```
const LinkElement = () => <Link to='/some-redirection-in-the-same-app'>Click here...</Link>

const EyelashGrowthData = [
    {
        key:"How does bimatoprost 0.03% ophthalmic solution work?",
        data: () => `It is believed the growth cycle (anagen) phase is increased of your eyelash hair cycle. Anagen is the
        growth phase of all hair. The increase in the length of the anagen phase therefore increases the
        number of hairs in this growth phase.`   
    },
    {
        key:"Is a doctor’s consultation and prescription required for this treatment?",
        data: () => <> Yes, this is a prescription-only medication to grow the eyelashes longer, fuller and darker, indicated
        for people with inadequate or not enough lashes. This treatment needs to be prescribed by a doctor
        to assure the proper treatment and use. Complete the <LinkElement/> now.</>  
    }
];
```

And then you would simple invoke the data function from within your second component. You could also handle strings as well as functions such as `{typeof item.data === 'function' ? item.data() : item.data }`.